# Make multiindex columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following strcuture:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(32).reshape((4,8)), 
            index = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=4),
            columns=['male ; 0', 'male ; 1','male ; 2','male ; 4','female ; 0','female ; 1','female ; 2','female ; 3',])
```

The column names are messy with a combination of two variable in the header name, and residual punctuation from the original spreadsheet.

What I want to do is set a column MultiIndex called sex and age in my dataframe.

I tried using `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` like this:

```
columns = [('Male', 0),('Male', 1),('Male', 2),('Male', 3),('Female', 0),('Female', 1),('Female', 2),('Female', 3)]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
```

And then naming the column indexes:

```
df.columns.names = ['Sex', 'Age']
```

This gives the result that I would like. However, my dataframes has ages to over 100 for each sex so this is not very practical.

Could someone please guide me on how to set MultiIndex columns from a tuple programatically.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Jaco's answer works nicely, but you can even create a `MultiIndex` from a product *directly* using `.from_product()`:

```
sex = ['Male', 'Female']
age = range(100)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([sex, age], names=['Sex', 'Age'])
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `itertools` module to generate your `columns` variable by taking the cartesian join of gender and the age range in your data, for example:

```
import itertools
max_age = 100
sex = ['Male','Female']
age = range(max_age)
columns=list(itertools.product(sex, age))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
df.columns.names = ['Sex', 'Age']
```

Answer (score 1):

## generate multiindex df from dict

This is especially convenient, if the multiindex columns can not be generated by a combinatoric operation.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame({("Male", 0): [1, 2], ("Male", 1): [3, 4], ("Female", 0): [5, 6], ("Female", "..."): [7, 8]})
  Male    Female    
     0  1      0 ...
0    1  3      5   7
1    2  4      6   8
```

If you want to set the column names of the df as well, use

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({("Male", 0): [1, 2], ("Male", 1): [3, 4], ("Female", 0): [5, 6], ("Female", "..."): [7, 8]})
>>> df.columns.names = ['Sex', 'Age']
>>> df
Sex Male    Female    
Age    0  1      0 ...
0      1  3      5   7
1      2  4      6   8
```

Answer (score 1):

## compact one-liner

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape((2,4)), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("m", 0), ("m", 1), ("f", 0), ("f", "...")], names=["sex", "age"]))
sex  m     f    
age  0  1  0 ...
0    0  1  2   3
1    4  5  6   7
```